# Creating portlet in liferay using plugin SDK

Tags: liferay

I was trying to create a portlet using plugin SDK in liferay from the command prompt (create.bat hello-world "Hello World") but every time i ended up with the below error.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9.
>    Required by:
>        :liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2:unspecified
>   Could not GET 'http://cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/pu
>   blic/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.pom'.
>   Connection to http://cdn.repository.liferay.com refused
>   
>   Please help me how can i get rid of this.

Thanks,
Sourav

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a glitch with the https certificate name not matching the hostname, as there's an https redirect when I access http://cdn.repository.liferay.com/ directly - the content is there, e.g. on http://cdn.repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.pom my browser shows it. For some reason the link you post has a space in it - check if this is due to some edit (try to find the path in the files of your SDK) that you did to the file or how else you got to post an invalid link. I've done nothing else but to remove that space.